# What does "GC (Allocation Failure)" mean in my ElasticSearch 5.6 logs?

Tags: java, database, elasticsearch, database-administration, database-performance

I see these constantly in my Elasticsearch 5.6.3 logs.  Is this a signal that I should scale up and add more RAM?  Or is this just normal operations for ElasticSearch?

```
    [GC (Allocation Failure) [ParNew
 Desired survivor size 11141120 bytes, new threshold 15 (max 15)
 - age 1: 1761848 bytes, 1761848 total
 - age 2: 126464 bytes, 1888312 total
 - age 3: 165056 bytes, 2053368 total
 - age 4: 50584 bytes, 2103952 total
 - age 5: 105120 bytes, 2209072 total
 - age 6: 99072 bytes, 2308144 total
 - age 7: 2024 bytes, 2310168 total
 - age 8: 95632 bytes, 2405800 total
 - age 9: 24960 bytes, 2430760 total
 - age 10: 62552 bytes, 2493312 total
 - age 11: 95816 bytes, 2589128 total
 - age 12: 54248 bytes, 2643376 total
 - age 13: 50704 bytes, 2694080 total
 - age 14: 856 bytes, 2694936 total
 - age 15: 4736 bytes, 2699672 total
 : 134451K->3691K(152320K), 0.0031179 secs] 375121K->244360K(500480K), 0.0032213 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.01, real=0.00 secs] 
 [GC (Allocation Failure) [ParNew
 Desired survivor size 11141120 bytes, new threshold 15 (max 15)
 - age 1: 731712 bytes, 731712 total
 - age 2: 447632 bytes, 1179344 total
 - age 3: 120736 bytes, 1300080 total
 - age 4: 165056 bytes, 1465136 total
 - age 5: 50584 bytes, 1515720 total
 - age 6: 105120 bytes, 1620840 total
 - age 7: 98552 bytes, 1719392 total
 - age 8: 1872 bytes, 1721264 total
 - age 9: 94736 bytes, 1816000 total
 - age 10: 24664 bytes, 1840664 total
 - age 11: 62256 bytes, 1902920 total
 - age 12: 95816 bytes, 1998736 total
 - age 13: 53696 bytes, 2052432 total
 - age 14: 4112 bytes, 2056544 total
 - age 15: 856 bytes, 2057400 total
 : 134251K->3308K(152320K), 0.0042321 secs] 374920K->243982K(500480K), 0.0043257 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.01, real=0.00 secs]
```

Answer (score 4):

`GC (Allocation Failure)` is a JVM message (not an Elasticsearch-specific one) that *can* be a sign that there's memory pressure, but it's not catastropic to the JVM (that would cause a `OutOfMemoryError` log line). It can also be completely innocuous.

`GC (Allocation Failure)` means that the Java garbage collector tried to run, ran out of space in the heap, then tried to allocate more memory. It's not a bad sign, necessarily. If you're receiving `OutOfMemoryError` errors and the JVM is crashing, then you know you're in trouble.

**Side note / disclaimer / full disclosure / whatever the heck you want:** I work for a DBaaS company that hosts Elasticsearch clusters.